# In MVC3 Razor, how do I get the html of a rendered view inside an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Does anybody know how to get the generated html of a view inside an action?

Is it something like this:

```
public ActionResult Do()
{
    var html = RenderView("hello", model);
...
}
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I use a static method in a class I called `Utilities.Common` I pass views back to the client as properties of JSON objects constantly so I had a need to render them to a string. Here ya go:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

This will work for full views as well as partial views, just change `ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView` to `ViewEngines.Engines.FindView`.

Comment: FindView needs another parameter (`masterName`) which you would specify null. Also I recommend saving and restoring (after rendering) controller.ViewData.Model in case the method is called on the current controller instance and model has been assigned before this call.

Comment: Also, you don't need to do sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString(), sw.ToString() will do just nice.

Comment: You should also call viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View)

Comment: Well this is giving a problem for me as Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: controllerContext how can o fix this problem?

Comment: @HaBo You need to pass in the existing Controller into this method, so the View has to be in it.

Comment: It works great, but I wouldn't want to catch and render exceptions in my live code.

Comment: @AlexFord hi Alex i am new to MVC and using razor..when calling your method "RenderPartialViewToString" what is the way to pass the controller instance from the view?? please help

Comment: If you are calling it from within the controller itself then just pass `this` as the controller argument. `RenderPartialViewToString(this, "index", viewModel)`. I do think it is silly that there is no easier way to simply invoke the view engine and get back a string, but in ASP.NET the view engine needs reference to the controller instance in order to compile the view. I'm a nodeJS developer now and view engines in node are entire separate modules that you can invoke manually or with an MVC framework like [express](http://expressjs.com).

Comment: @PauloManuelSantos I agree with you. I wrote this years ago and I don't know what I was thinking by including error handling in the answer. I have updated the answer to exclude the try/catch. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer by @Chev above is good, but I wanted to render the result of a specific *action*, not just a particular *view*.

Also, I needed to be able to pass parameters to that action rather than rely on injecting a model.

So I came up with my own method, that I put in the base class of my controllers (making it available to them all):

```
    protected string RenderViewResultAsString(ViewResult viewResult)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            this.RenderViewResult(viewResult, stringWriter);

            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void RenderViewResult(ViewResult viewResult, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        var viewEngineResult = this.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(
            this.ControllerContext, 
            viewResult.ViewName, 
            viewResult.MasterName);
        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        try
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                this.ControllerContext, 
                view, 
                this.ViewData, 
                this.TempData, 
                textWriter);

            view.Render(viewContext, textWriter);
        }
        finally
        {
            viewEngineResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(this.ControllerContext, view);
        }
    }
```

Suppose I have an action called `Foo` that takes a model object and some other parameters, which together influence what view will be used:

```
    public ViewResult Foo(MyModel model, int bar)
    {
        if (bar == 1)
            return this.View("Bar1");
        else
            return this.View("Bar2", model);
    }
```

Now, if I want to get the result of calling action `Foo`, I can simply get the `ViewResult` by invoking the `Foo` method, and then call `RenderViewResultAsString` to get the HTML text:

```
    var viewResult = this.Foo(model, bar);

    var html = this.RenderViewResultAsString(viewResult);
```