# How can I get the current html-code as a string[] to a Controller (FileStreamResult)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In a View I want download the current view as a pdf-file. How can you give the contents of the view to the controller?

```
<td><span>
   <a href='<%: Url.Action("ListToPdf", 
     new { AHtmlContents = this.SourceCode.ToString()})%>'
     target="_blank">Download list</a>
</span></td>
```

Comment: Have you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442343/get-html-from-mvc-4-view-into-a-string?

Comment: Why don't you create html on server side itself from your data instead of taking it from view? I know it will add more code but I think it will be easy for you to manage.