# Get HTML generated by View()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to save HTML that's being generated by

`return View("view name", ComplexModel);` in Controller's method with `IActionResult` return type

Is it possible to extract that html without obtaining it from user side by e.g JavaScript?

Something like:

`string html = View("view name", ComplexModel).RawHtml;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render an ASP.NET MVC view as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/how-to-render-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get html from MVC 4 view into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442343/get-html-from-mvc-4-view-into-a-string)

Comment: @AFriend @BrankVictoria are you sure it applies to .net core?  ``'Engines' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines' ``

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31906578/6144259) seems to address core 2 directly