# Save view as html file after rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, itext7

Is it possible to save a rendered view as html file?

I need to save a view as an "Testfile.html" after Razor and javascript has rendered. Is it possible?

What i am trying to do, is take the saved view, that includes canvas created using chart.js, and save them as an html file. Afterwards i want to convert the html file to a pdf using iText7

Comment: You need to call that controller action, which returns the view, from C# using HTTPClient, the response will have the HTML content of the view. You can save it as an html file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442343/get-html-from-mvc-4-view-into-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MVC3 Razor, how do I get the html of a rendered view inside an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692131/in-mvc3-razor-how-do-i-get-the-html-of-a-rendered-view-inside-an-action)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the below code :

First of all there is no need to save the HTML as a physical file, you can just call the razor engine renderer from within your controller, for example, so as to return the final string response.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then you can pass this response to your exporter so that it can return to you the pdf file, that you will later on return directly to the client

```
              string htmlContent = RenderRazorViewToString("SomeViewDefinedAsPartial", ReportModel);

////    fetch view's pdf styles
                string CSSContent = "";

            var byteRslt = PDFExporter.ConvertToPDF(htmlContent, CSSContent);
```

Important: HTML to PDF renderers usually dont play well enough with dynamic pages that require javascript to do initializations, but i hope this answer will help you move forwards in your requirement/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the View to pdf file using `wkhtmltopdf`

wkhtmltopdf need to be installed on the server and its path is used in the web.config from here the c# code will use this path and convert it to pdf file.