# Is it possible to get raw HTML from Razor/Blazor components?

Tags: razor, blazor, mailkit, mimekit, blazor-client-side

I'd like to set up a "mailer/newsletter" using MailKit. My site stack is based off of Blazor web assembly and uses .Razor components.

I'm wondering if there is a way to consume a razor component I've written to output HTML into the MimeMessage object I'm using to generate my email body and what that architecture would look like / the best way to accomplish this?

Similar question (though not Blazor):

- [Can I use an ASP.Net MVC Razor view to generate an nicely formatted HTML Body as the input for an email sent from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266586/can-i-use-an-asp-net-mvc-razor-view-to-generate-an-nicely-formatted-html-body-as)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer since I just saw this question: I wrote an alternative system called [BlazorTemplater](https://github.com/conficient/blazortemplater) which uses `.razor` files instead of `.cshtml` since I had exactly this problem.

You can convert your templates to `.razor` format and then use [BlazorTemplater](https://github.com/conficient/blazortemplater) to render to HTML:

```cs
var html = new ComponentRenderer<MyRazorClass>()
   .Set(c => c.SomeParameter = someValue)
   .Render();
```

It supports parameters, DI injection and nested components so you should find it useful! It's also much easier to set up and works in Razor Class Libraries too.

Comment: Gosh, I asked this question 2 years ago now...so crazy. Thanks so much for this. Marking as correct answer. I'm in the process of installing your package and consuming it now. Will report back!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Blazor with MailKit here: [Google Email Viewer in Server Side Blazor](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4357/Google-Email-Viewer-in-Server-Side-Blazor.aspx)

I use `MarkupString` to display the email content like this:

```
@using MimeKit
@using MessageReader
@strError
<div style="padding:2px; vertical-align:top">
    <div><i>@MimeKitMessage.Date.ToString()</i></div>
    <div><b>From:</b> @MimeKitMessage.From.ToString()</div>
    <div><b>To:</b> @MimeKitMessage.To.ToString()</div>
    <div><b>Subject:</b> @MimeKitMessage.Subject</div>
    <br />
    <div>@((MarkupString)@htmlEmail)</div>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public Message paramMessage { get; set; }
    MimeMessage MimeKitMessage;
    string strError = "";
    string htmlEmail = "";
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        try
        {
            if (paramMessage != null)
            {
                string converted = paramMessage.Raw.Replace('-', '+');
                converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
                byte[] decodedByte = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);
                using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(decodedByte))
                {
                    // Convert to MimeKit from GMail
                    // Load a MimeMessage from a stream
                    MimeKitMessage = MimeMessage.Load(stream);
                    // Convert any embedded images
                    var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor();
                    MimeKitMessage.Accept(visitor);
                    htmlEmail = visitor.HtmlBody;
                    //If the email has attachments we can get them here
                    //var attachments = visitor.Attachments;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because I misinterpreted the answer. I realized my mistake but can't remove the downvote. RIP

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe - No problem :)