# ASP.NET MVC 3 get HTML from viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, viewmodel, actionresult, abcpdf

I have a Controller with a method like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CustomerInfoViewModel viewModel = CustomerInfoModel.Load();
    return View("Report", viewModel);
}
```

Now I'd like to create another method which does the same than this one but returns de HTML (string) instead of the ActionResult. Is there any way to get the HTML that an ActionResult would render or something like that?

Why do I need this? This is a report that I show in HTML. But the user has the possibility to download the PDF with the report. To do that I'm using [ABCPdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm). I have to ways to build the PDF file.

1. From a HTML string. (That's why I want to do what I'm asking).
2. From an URL. In this case the server starts a request to that URL (I can use the URL to the method posted above). The problem is that this request is a new one, so I lose the session information (which is used in the report).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public ActionResult GetPDF()
    {
     // Do your report generation here
     byte[] Buffer = [Get the rendered pdf file]
     return File( Buffer, "application/pdf", Server.HtmlEncode("[Report Name]") );
    }
```

Comment: @Rajkumar R: The problem is to generate the report. I can do it with the HTML (don't know how to get the HTML from a ViewModel) or I do it through the URL in which case I need some "magic trick" to avoid loosing the session information.

Comment: @Diego: Can i know why aren't you using session Management and cookies. You can use session object to store ViewModel and retrieve it in the subsequent request to generate the PDF.

Comment: @Rajkumar R: If I could use the session info between both request there would be no problem because I could generate the report in the second request without any trouble. The problem is that such as they are two different request the session information is different, they have different session ID.

Comment: @Diego: I Hope this helps   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692131/how-to-render-a-razor-view-get-the-html-of-a-rendered-view-inside-an-action)

Comment: @Rajkumar R: The link worked great. Please update your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!! :)