# How to load a Razor view and render it on the fly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, content-management-system, render

I have a custom CMS built with ASP.NET WebForms (you can see it in action at [Thought Results](http://www.thoughtresults.com)). Now I want to build it using ASP.NET MVC 3 (or even 4). I don't want to change the architecture that much, therefore, I need to dynamically load a Razor View, and dynamically run a Model Loader method, and give the model to the view dynamically, then render the view, and return the result rendered string, all done in server.

In ASP.NET WebForms, my code is:

```
string renderedString = "LatestArticles.ascx".LoadControl().GetReneredString();
```

Now, I'd like to be able to write a code line like:

```
string renderedString = 
"LatestArticles.cshtml".LoadView().BindModel("ModelBinderMethodName").Render();
```

I know about many questions about rendering a view (view to string), but  I didn't find what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may checkout [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This is cool. But I prefer not to be dependent on a third party library. +1.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, well, then you could try to render the Razor view to a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692131/how-to-render-a-razor-view-get-the-html-of-a-rendered-view-inside-an-action/4692447#4692447