# Can I call an ActionResult from within an ActionResult and work with the returned HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In MVC3 Razor, how do I get the html of a rendered view inside an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692131/in-mvc3-razor-how-do-i-get-the-html-of-a-rendered-view-inside-an-action)

Ok, here is the scenario. I have an Action Result that returns a nicely formatted Partial View. I want the exact same HTML result to be sent out in an email that is triggered from another Action Result. I realize there are a number of ways to do this. It would take forever to format an HTML string in the Controller or Model. I could also read the file contents from disk, etc. Currently I am doind this, but there must be a better more acceptable way to accomplish this in my controller:

```
// MAKE AN HTTP REQUEST FROM CONTROLLER A AND GET THE DETAILS FROM ANOTER CONTROLLER/ACTION
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("UrlToAnotherActionResult");
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
var html = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

I then take the html result and use it as the body of my email.

Is there a more elegant way to get the results from another Action than this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the RenderPartialViewToString functionality defined here:

http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

It's seems to work quite well.