# MVC3 - Allow view to be rendered as html or JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, view, render

I want to build an API that will allow to present a view inside:

1. Iframe (regular view).
2. Or as a JS (document.write).

Some time a developer will use Iframe, and sometime he will use the script.

So one time you can call the Iframe:

```
//will render <html><body><div>I am a div</div></body></html>
<iframe src="/page/mysqldata?mod=iframe"></iframe>
```

and one time I want to get the html as JS

```
//will render document.write('<div>I am a div</div>');
<script  src="/page/mysqldata?mod=js"></script>
```

Do you know a tutorial of how to set it up?
BTW, my views are complex  with a lot of `@Html` calls with `RenderSection`s and `@Html.Partial`  calls.

The bottom line is that I want to provide html with 2 different methods, iframe and script but i want to keep a single view.

Thanks

Comment: can use AJAX to retrieve html with script. Not clear what you are trying to do exactly with script vs iframe, or what determines which case to use. AJAX is likely the answer

Comment: Did you try to expose that as 2 different actions in you controller? On action will return a jsonresult another will return a viewresult.

Comment: @Ikaso - thanks, but how can I render the html view as json? can you post an example? this :  `return Json(View(viewModel),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`  will not work...

Comment: @charlietfl - I have edit the question and the sample code, hope it helps. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF - you don't render the view as Json. One method return JsonResult another method renders a ViewResult. If you want to achieve maximum reuse you can make both methods call a third private method that returns the same viewmodel. On the method that returns a view you send the viewmodel as the Model. On the method that returns JsonResult you send the viewmodel to JsonResult so that it will be serialized as Json.

Comment: can't you just add the iframe with script? Or have you looked into using AJAX?

Comment: @Ikaso - Please see my html comments above the sample code, I dont think you understood my question completely. - Thanks

Comment: Where you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take Alex's implementation of `RenderPartialViewToString()` from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692447/1373170), which lets you render a view to a string directly inside the controller.

You could create a View and a Partial. The Partial having all the content bound to a model, and the View could add the `<html><body>`...etc.
Create all your views using Razor, and make them as complex as you want, they are just regular views.

So now your controller should have two Actions:

1. For html content in iframe: Just renders the View, so it's a regular MVC action
2. For JS content: Call  `RenderPartialViewToString`, and instead of outputting html, do this:

   ```
   public JavaScriptResult AsJavascript()
   {
       var theModel = //create the model
       var content = // call to RenderPartialViewToString(this, "PartialViewName", theModel);
       var script = String.Format("document.write('{0}')",
              content.Replace("'", "\'").Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
       return this.JavaScript(script);
   }
   ```

I've had to do similar things in the past, however I used [jquery](http://jquery.com/) instead of direct document writes, so the code was a bit neater, by creating a `DIV`, setting the content with `div.html(content)`, and then appending that div to the body of the page. But the result should ultimately be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not missing something here, but your controller action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult MySqlData(string mod)
{
    if (string.Compare("js", mod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        return JavaScript("path_to_the_script");
    else if (string.Compare("iframe", mod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        return View("your_view_details_here");
    return HttpNotFound("explain why this action failed");
}
```