# In NancyFx Razor, how do I get the html of a rendered view inside an action?

Tags: razor, nancy

I have case like: [In MVC3 Razor, how do I get the html of a rendered view inside an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692131/in-mvc3-razor-how-do-i-get-the-html-of-a-rendered-view-inside-an-action) but I'm using NancyFx.

Anybody known, how to do it?

Comment: Addendum: https://gist.github.com/bhameyie/6314781  An extension to render view as string with NancyFx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I find answare:

in http://shanemitchell.ca/tag/nancyfx/

in that method, the html is in "var content".

```
 ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext = new ViewLocationContext()
        {
            Context = module.Context,
            ModuleName = module.GetType().Name,
            ModulePath = module.ModulePath
        };
        var rendered = module.ViewFactory.RenderView(viewName, model, viewLocationContext);
        var content = "";
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            rendered.Contents.Invoke(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        };
```